# Array index out of bound exception in quick sort algorithm

Tags: c#, sorting, quicksort

This is a typical quick sort algorithm where the pivot is the first element of the array

```
public static int Partition(int[] container, int low, int high) 
        {
            int pivot = container[low];
            int i = low, j = high;
            while (i<j) 
            {
                do
                {
                    i++;
                } while (container[i]<=pivot);//I am getting ArrayIndexOutBoundException here. 
                do
                {
                    j--;//Increment i until you find an element greater than the pivot
                } while (container[j]>pivot);
                if (i<j) 
                {
                   //Swapping
                    int temp = container[i];
                    container[i] = container[j];
                    container[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            int t2 = container[low];
            container[low] = container[j];
            container[j] = t2;
            return j;
        }


public void QuickSort(int[] container, int low, int high) 
        {
            if (low<high) 
            {
                int p = Partition(container, low, high);
                QuickSort(container, low, p);
                QuickSort(container,p+1,high);
            }
        }
```

In the partition method I am trying to increment the i value until the element is greater than the pivot and decrement the j until the element is smaller than the pivot.

I think that the while loop should avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, right?

Comment: Think about what happens if the container contains `{0,0,0}`, `low` is 0 and `high` is 2. Follow the code manually and determine what happens.

Comment: In code like this it is really easy to get some of by one-error. But these kinds of errors should be fairly easy to find and explain with a *debugger*. I would recommend reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).